# python. Ссылка не воспринимается

Tags: python

В общем, нужна переменная с ссылкой на сайт, но в этой ссылке есть японские иероглифы, из-за них ссылки читается но какого-то момента (до символов). Чем их заменить, или что с ними сделать, чтобы читались программой?

```
url = 'ht.tp://seoji.nl.go.kr/landingPage/SearchList.do?q=%28**연재%29&rows=50#'
```

Comment: "чтобы читались программой"... какой?

Comment: pycharm - эту использую

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "читается до какого-то момента"? Если то что PyCharm в коде не полностью подчеркивает ссылку, то это на функциональность вашей программы никак не повлияет.